# Paste to another cell and WS while looping and shifting down a row

Tags: vba, excel, function, loops

I am looking for some help in getting this code to run properly. I've gotten some help with the first part from some great people here!
Basically, the code I have now sets ranges in between cells formatted bold, as the bold represents a date. I am trying to find the individual segments in column A and copy the coresponding number in column D to another worksheet in column C. If the value is not found in the range, the row output should shift down one without filling in anything.
Here is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub DataBetween()
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Dim dataWS As Worksheet
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set dataWS = thisWB.sheets("FC01.RPT")
    Set MoBWS = thisWB.sheets("Mix of Business")

    '--- find the first bold cell...
    Dim nextBoldCell As range
    Set nextBoldCell = FindNextBoldInColumn(dataWS.range("A1"))

    '--- now note the start of the data and find the next bold cell
    Dim startOfDataRow As Long
    Dim endOfDataRow As Long
    Dim lastRowOfAllData As Long
    startOfDataRow = 3
    'Set lastRowOfAllData = dataWS.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    '--- this loop is for all the data sets...
    Do
        endOfDataRow = EndRowOfDataSet(dataWS, startOfDataRow)

        '--- this loop is to work through one data set
        For i = startOfDataRow To endOfDataRow
        sheets("FC01.RPT").Select
        Cells.Find(What:="Individual return guest").Activate

        range("D" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
        Selection.copy
            sheets("Plan").Select
            range("C3").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        Next i
            startOfDataRow = endOfDataRow + 1
    Loop

    'Do While endOfDataRow < lastRowOfAllData

errhandler:
    MsgBox "No Cells containing specified text found"

End Sub


Public Function FindNextBoldInColumn(ByRef startCell As range, _
                                     Optional columnNumber As Long = 1) As range
    '--- beginning at the startCell row, this function check each
    '    lower row in the same column and stops when it encounters
    '    a BOLD font setting
    Dim checkCell As range
    Set checkCell = startCell
    Do While Not checkCell.Font.bold
        Set checkCell = checkCell.Offset(1, 0)
        If checkCell.Row = checkCell.Parent.Rows.Count Then
            '--- we've reached the end of the column, so
            '    return nothing
            Set FindNextBoldInColumn = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop
    Set FindNextBoldInColumn = checkCell
End Function


Private Function EndRowOfDataSet(ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
                                 ByVal startRow As Long, _
                                 Optional maxRowsInDataSet As Long = 50) As Long
    '--- checks each row below the starting row for either a BOLD cell
    '    or, if no BOLD cells are detected, returns the last row of data
    Dim checkCell As range
    Set checkCell = ws.Cells(startRow, 1)  'assumes column "A"
    Dim i As Long
    For i = startRow To maxRowsInDataSet
        If ws.Cells(startRow, 1).Font.bold Then
            EndRowOfDataSet = i - 1
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    '--- if we make it here, we haven't found a BOLD cell, so
    '    find the last row of data
    EndRowOfDataSet = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

The code keeps crashing. How can I make it so the output line shifts down one when looping though a range, no matter if it finds the value or not?

Does anyone know what do to?
Here is a snapshot of the data I am working with:

[image]

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I don't see any `"Find Individual Rate guest").Activate`, do you mean the commented out `Cells.Find(What:="Individual Rate guest").Activate` line??

Comment: I updated the code now, sorry for that and thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: It's probably crashing because if `Find` doesn't find anything, it will throw an error. You either need to use `On Error Resume Next` around that line, or `If Cells.Find(What:=Individual return guest") <> Nothing Then`...

Comment: I tried this and it still just keeps looping and eventually crashes. I think I am stuck in the loop and have no where to go, so it keeps looping on the same cell.. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your `Do` loop has no criteria to let it exit - typically when using a `Do` loop (and not a `Do While` loop) there will be some kind of `Exit Do` criteria, for example, if `startOfDataRow = 100 Then Exit Do`. So yeah, it's going to keep going forever because you've given it no reason not to :)

Comment: Here's what I'm going to suggest - I think you have way too much here for what you're trying to accomplish. I honestly think you should start over, try recording a macro and after finishing that, open a new question with that code. Then explain **in detail** what you're trying to accomplish, and we'll finish the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed all your "blocks" end with some "Summe" occurrence in column A, and data begins at row 14

then I'd go this way:

```
Sub mm()
    Dim iArea As Long

    With Worksheets("FC01.RPT")
        With .Range("A14", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .Cells(2, 1).Value = "Summe"
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Summe*"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '.Offset(-1)
                For iArea = 1 To .Areas.Count - 1
                    With .Parent.Range(.Areas(iArea).Offset(1), .Areas(iArea + 1).Offset(-1))
                        Worksheets("Plan").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Cells, "Individual*", .Offset(, 3))
                    End With
                Next
            End With
            .Cells(2, 1).ClearContents
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! It works partially. The first 10 ranges summ the corret amount, but thereafter I am getting wrong answers. The code also doesn't run through the entire worksheet, but only goes through around half of the dates (15 of 31). 
Any suggestions on what to tweak for this?

Comment: The reason it gives that error is because not all first lines are "Individual Rate Guest". They all begin with "Individual" but can differ in the following words.. How can I ammend this?

Comment: see edited answer. if it solves your question you may consider marking it as accepted. thank you

Comment: Hi DisplayName! I really appreciate your help. I just tried it again to make sure I am doing it right and it is still giving me the same output as with the other code. I think there is a bug in it somehow bc it loops through the ranges and gives the correct output in descending order in the output sheet, but only for the first 10-15 outputs. Then it keeps overriding the first output cell (D1) with the following sums. Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: I added another screenshot and highlighted the field that are incorrect.
The left column B is what it should be and column D is the what the code is delivering

Comment: Yes I did, you changed the Individual Rate guest to the Summe

Comment: Almost works - the only thing now is that it doesn't skip down a row if there is no "Summe" found in the range. Is there a way to fix this as well? Otherwise I can just input the "Summe" (or another common value) in the fields that are missing one. This helps so much though!!